# Copy pointer array to NSData and then to pointer array

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a problem with understand some basics. I want create pointer array (a1) copy it to NSData (c1) than again create pointer array (b1) from NSData and check if content of a1 and b1 is the same.

But I face with two erors:

**First** is "incorrect checksum for freed object" when I want create NSData dataWithBytes:length:

**Second** bytes in a1 and b1 aren't the same. 
Could someone tell me why? For record I use xcode5 with arc.

```
- (void) testCopyBuffer {
    int const bufferSize =4096;
    int* a1;
    a1 = (int*)malloc(bufferSize);

    for (int i=0; i<bufferSize; i++) {
        a1[i] = i;
    }

    NSData *c1 = [NSData dataWithBytes:a1 length:bufferSize];

    int* b1;
    b1 = malloc(bufferSize);
    [c1 getBytes:b1 length:bufferSize];

    for (int i=0; i<bufferSize; i++) {
        XCTAssertTrue(a1[i]==b1[i], "Powinny być takie same");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm missing something -- where is the pointer array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't allocate the right amount of memory.
For `bufferSize` number of `int`s, you need to allocate

```
a1 = malloc(bufferSize * sizeof(int));
```

And later consequently

```
NSData *c1 = [NSData dataWithBytes:a1 length:(bufferSize * sizeof(int))];
```

etc. In your case,

```
for (int i=0; i<bufferSize; i++) {
        a1[i] = i;
    }
```

writes beyond the allocated memory, which can lead to all kinds of undefined
behaviour.

Comment: xD totaly forgot about it. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, the problem would be that you clobbered something in heap when you inited the array, so anything after that was bogus.

Comment: @MartinR Could you point out the problem here that leads to writing beyond the allocated memory in that `for` loop? Is it because of the wrong number of `bufferSize`? Thanks.

Comment: @Unheilig: One `int` occupies `sizeof(int)` bytes (usually 4 bytes, but that may depend on the platform). So for an array of 10 integers, you would need 40 bytes. In contrast to the C++ `new` operator, `malloc()` is dumb and just allocates the given number of *bytes*.

Comment: @MartinR Good call about the platform. Just on top off my head: has there ever been a `macro` or the likes where they used to check against platform and used it along with `malloc` in the old days?

Comment: @Unheilig: I am not sure if I understand your question. `sizeof()` was always used to calculate the number of bytes to allocate, and does it the "right thing" on all platforms.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, updated my comment: I meant `malloc` not `sizeof`.

Comment: @Dudi: Let me know if you need more information. - Otherwise you might consider to "accept" the answer if it helped.